# I am not able to get the proper value of key_on in Choropleth constructor

Tags: python, geojson, choropleth

I am trying to draw a choropleth map for Indian state population. This is my code:

```
india_geo=r'e:/coursera/indiageo.geojson
world_map=folium.Map(location=[20.5937,78.9629],zoom_start=4)
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=india_geo.geojson,
    data=df_pop,
    key_on='features.properties.ID_1',
    columns=['Name', 'TOT_P'], 
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Distribution'
    ).add_to(world_map)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(world_map)
world_map
```

The problem is that when I am running the code, I am getting white screen. My dataframe consist of the name of the state and its population:

```
  Name             TOT_P
0   JAMMU & KASHMIR    1493299
1   HIMACHAL PRADESH   392126
2   UTTARAKHAND        291903
3   RAJASTHAN          9238534
4   UTTAR PRADESH      1134273
```

The link to the geojson file is following:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geohacker/india/master/district/india_district.geojson

Answer (score 0):

You need to add feature on 'id' to access features

```
with open(r'\india.GEOJSON') as f:
    geojson_counties = json.load(f)
for i in geojson_counties['features']:
    i['id'] = i['properties']['NAME_1']
```

and set key_on as

```
key_on='feature.id'
```